# What does $Z_2(S)$ mean where $S$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

In an article by Bob Oliver "Simple fusion systems over p-groups with abelian subgroup of index p" in Notation 2.2., he defines a set $Z_2 = Z_2(S)$ where $S$ is a nonabelian $p$-group. The problem is that I don't know what $Z_2(S)$ means. I know $Z(S)$ is the center, but I have never seen $Z_2(S)$. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Perhaps a [group-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) is meant? A bit like polynomials, but with coefficients drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and exponents from $S$?

Comment: Maybe it is the second center, Z(G/Z).

Comment: Second center would make sense. Because later he talks about $Z_2/Z$ where $Z= Z(S)$, so $Z(S)$ is a subgroup of $Z_2(S)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i.m. soloveichik points out in the comments, $Z_2(G)$ presumably refers to the [second center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29#Higher_centers) of the group $G$, i.e. the second term in the [upper central series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Upper_central_series).

This is indeed a subgroup of $G$, and it has several equivalent definitions:

- It is the inverse image of $Z\bigl(G/Z(G)\bigr)$ under the quotient homomorphism $G \to G/Z(G)$.
- It is the set $\{g\in G \mid [g,h]\in Z(G)\text{ for all }h\in G\}$.
- It is the set $\{g\in G \mid [[g,h],k]=1\text{ for all }h,k\in G\}$.

Note that $Z_2(G)$ is a normal (and indeed characteristic) subgroup of $G$, and that $Z_2(G)$ always contains $Z(G)$.  Moreover, $Z_2(G)$ is equal to $G$ if and only if $G$ is [nilpotent of class 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group), i.e. if and only if $G$ is a [central extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_extension_%28mathematics%29#Central_extension) of an abelian group.